# Codeigniter DB get query results that match their stored types

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I just recently noticed that my int's and boolean's and all else are coming out of the DB as strings. Is there any means of which I can tell the DB helper to stop that behavior and give me the actual type from the DB rather than casting it all as strings?

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following and works as you demand:

> table `users`
>
> ```
> id: int
> name: varchar(256)
> ```

```
// Model: users_model
function get_users() {
    $sql = 'SELECT id, name
            FROM users';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();
}

// Controller
function test() {
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $users = $this->users_model->get_users();
    var_dump( $users[0] );
}
```

And this is the result

> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(87) ["name"]=> string(4) "John" }